# Call BaseState function instead of Derived function when using std::variant<...>

Tags: c++, overloading, std-variant

I am experimenting with finate state machines and std::variant<..>

std::variant will hold all possible states
The states will be defined in State classes.

What I wanted was to have a BaseState class, in which "generic events" should be handled.
With derived State classes handling specific states.

```
struct LightOn;
struct LightOff;

struct Toggle;
struct Reset;

using State = std::variant<LightOn,LightOff>;
using Event = std::variant<Toggle,Reset>;

struct BaseState
{
    void on_enter(){Serial.printf("BaseState enter\r\n");};
    void on_event (const Reset &r);
};

struct LightOn : BaseState
{
    LightOn(){Serial.printf("LightOn constructor\r\n");};
    void on_event(const Event &e);
    void on_exit(){Serial.printf("LightOn exit\r\n");}
    void on_enter(){Serial.printf("LightOn enter\r\n");}
};

struct LightOff : BaseState
{
    LightOff(){Serial.printf("LightOff constructor\r\n");};
    void on_event(const Event &e);
    void on_exit(){Serial.printf("LightOff exit\r\n");}
};

struct Toggle
{
    Toggle(){Serial.printf("Struct Toggle\r\n");};
};

struct Reset
{
    Reset(){Serial.printf("Struct Reset\r\n");};
};

void LightOn::on_event(const Event &e){Serial.printf("LightOn event\r\n");};
void LightOff::on_event(const Event &e){Serial.printf("LightOff event\r\n");};
void BaseState::on_event(const Reset &r){Serial.printf("BaseState reset\r\n");};
```

The question I have is in the `on_event` function.

There is a specific one on Reset in the Basestate `void on_event(const Reset &r);`
And a more generic one in LightOn and LightOff `void on_event(const Event &e);` (using Event = std::variant<Toggle,Reset>;)

But when I do

```
LightOn n;
n.on_event(Reset{});
```

The on_event from LightOn is called, not the one from BaseState.

Is there a way to achieve : Call BaseState function when a BaseState function is available for this specific event ?

Answer (score 1):

Similar thing was answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35870081/c-base-class-function-overloading-in-a-subclass).

The name lookup stops at the sub class (because there is a match there).

You can use `using` to introduce the function from the base class (`BaseState`) into the same scope. (This will make it follow the usual overloading rules, in this case picking the exact match, which is the function from the base class.)

```cpp
struct LightOn;
struct LightOff;

struct Toggle;
struct Reset;

using State = std::variant<LightOn,LightOff>;
using Event = std::variant<Toggle,Reset>;

struct BaseState
{
    void on_enter(){Serial.printf("BaseState enter\r\n");};
    void on_event (const Reset &r);
};

struct LightOn : public BaseState
{
    LightOn(){Serial.printf("LightOn constructor\r\n");};
    using BaseState::on_event; // <-- Added to the scope
    void on_event(const Event &e); 
    void on_exit(){Serial.printf("LightOn exit\r\n");}
    void on_enter(){Serial.printf("LightOn enter\r\n");}
};

struct LightOff : public BaseState
{
    LightOff(){Serial.printf("LightOff constructor\r\n");};
    void on_event(const Event &e);
    void on_exit(){Serial.printf("LightOff exit\r\n");}
};

struct Toggle
{
    Toggle(){Serial.printf("Struct Toggle\r\n");};
};

struct Reset
{
    Reset(){Serial.printf("Struct Reset\r\n");};
};

void LightOn::on_event(const Event &e){Serial.printf("LightOn event\r\n");};
void LightOff::on_event(const Event &e){Serial.printf("LightOff event\r\n");};
void BaseState::on_event(const Reset &r){Serial.printf("BaseState reset\r\n");};
```

Also, take a look at [Boost compile-time FSM generator example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/mpl/doc/paper/html/example.html). It seems to accomplish the same goal as yours.